# Generating checkboxes in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I want to generate some checkboxes depending on select value. So i have select tag:

```html
<%= f.collection_select :type, RequestType.order(:typeName), :id, :typeName,
 {include_blank:true }, {:class => "types"} %>
```

When the value of select changes i want to generate some checkboxes, for that i have div:

```html
<div id="sub_types"> </div>
```

where i want to generate my checkboxes

```html
def show_sub_types
 @rtype = params[:id];
        @stypes = RequestSubType.where("request_type_id=?", @rtype).all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  format.html
 end
end
```

My method grabs all subtypes and passes them to js file  show_sub_types.js.erb

```html
$("#sub_types").html("");
$("#sub_types").append("<%= j render 'show_sub_types', stypes: @stypes %>");
```

In my js file i render partial show_sub_types.html.erb in which i want to generate my checkboxes:

```html
<% stypes.each do |type| %>
 <%= check_box_tag "subtype", type.id %>
 <%= type.subTypeName %>
 <br>
<% end %>
```

In my partial i do something like this.
This code generate me my checkboxes. They look like that:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="subtype" id="subtype" value="1">
```

But now i don't know how to submit these checkbox values with my form.I want to store multiple checkbox values in db as array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this

```
<% stypes.each do |type| %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'stype_ids[]', type.id %>
  <%= type.subTypeName %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You'll want to put `type.subTypeName` into a `label` element and wrap `check_box_tag` with it so that the label is clickable. Easy change but a vast improvement for the user.